# Why does my simple C++ GUI application show a message box in Chinese?

Tags: c++, winapi

[image]

Oh as for the whole (LPCWSTR) casting thing: It wouldn't compile unless I put those in. It gave me this error message:

> Error  1   error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [22]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: I don't know why, but your question title made me LMFAO. :'D

Comment: I wonder what these characters mean...

Comment: it's garbage chinese, meaning it doesn't mean anything. 你懂不懂？

Comment: In general, don't cast things just to satisfy the compiler.  If you think you need to write a cast, you should know _exactly_ what the cast will do and why it's necessary.  If you don't, ask for help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put an L infront of your string to make it a wide string. L"Goodbye cruel World"

Then you won't need the cast.

You can also use the TEXT("") macro that will create an unicode string or ascii string depending on your configuration settings.

The reason you were seeing chinese is that MessageBox was interpreting an ascii string as unicode.

Comment: Yup. Unlike the rest of the world, which does Unicode via UTF-8 encoding, so that plain ol' ASCII characters just work, Microsoft decided to do the whole WCHAR UTF-16 thing. It makes the code pretty non-portable and locks it into the Microsoft world, which is of course what they want. (There are ways around that, but they aren't obvious to the novice programmer.)

Comment: UTF-8 did not exist when NT was created (That is the excuse they are using anyway) You can probably find a post about it @ http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/

Answer (score 6):

You already have your answer, but this is a good example of why you should use avoid casts.  Yes, a cast will get your code to compile, but unless you understand what is going on, most likely you've just created a bug.

In general, my 3 rules of casting are:

1. Don't cast (fix the code).
2. Don't cast (adjust your types to stop needing the cast)
3. Okay, cast, but revisit your decision tomorrow and see if you can do #1 or #2.

Answer (score 0):

My strong guess is that your source file has the wrong encoding. Can you check whether it's saved in some Unicode flavour, most likely UTF-16?

Comment: I don't know what IDE you are on, but you should have a "character set" option in your "save as..." dialog, or somewhere in your menus.