# Why does message box in C++ show chinese message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my simple C++ GUI application show a message box in Chinese?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079828/why-does-my-simple-c-gui-application-show-a-message-box-in-chinese)

I have implemented this block of code as below in Visual C++:

```
int nResult=MessageBox(NULL,
                       (LPCWSTR)"An example of Cancel,Retry,Continue",
                       (LPCWSTR)"Message Box!",
                        MB_ICONWARNING|MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
```

however, no matter what i tried, it always show a message box in chinese! Therefore, i just want to ask for any solution for my problem and why there is chinese message here. Thanks you!

Comment: Oh my god, again this trivial question. :-)

Comment: I got Chinese too! Why are we all getting Chinese? Are there just so many Chinese charactrs that any time a string points to some random place on memory overwhelming chances are it will be Chineses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to place 'L' before the string literal. Modify as follows:

```
int nResult=MessageBox(NULL,
                   L"An example of Cancel,Retry,Continue",
                   L"Message Box!",
                   MB_ICONWARNING|MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
```

In C++ unicode string literals are prefixed with `L`. If you don't put the prefix, casting to 'unicode string constant' won't help and causes incorrect interpreting of the memory location.

Comment: Can you point me to where I can learn more about this specific type of casting? As far as I knew, Usually casting consisted of `(Type) thingToBeCasted`. I don't understand how we cast to `L` and what it means.

Comment: This is not a cast. If you put `(LPCWSTR)` before your string literal, it **is** a cast, but putting `L` character before the string literal, tells the compiler to *interpret* the string as a Unicode string. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.ASPX) for more information.

Comment: Make it wide-character strings, and you are right.

Answer (score 5):

You are expecting a cast of a pointer from one type to another to change the value pointed to. That's not what C++ casts do. They just tell the compiler to assume the pointer points to the new type. To specify a [wide literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/69ze775t%28v=vs.80%29), use `L` before the quotes (or [new string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#New_string_literals) if your compiler supports them). And get rid of the cast, it's just obscuring the bug.

Answer (score 4):

As David said you've casted an ASCII string to a UNICODE string. Use the _TEXT("Your string") macro instead.

You can't just interpret ASCII bytes as a UNICODE string or bad things will happen.

Edit: Also if you want ASCII strings you can explicitly call MessageBoxA() or change to multi byte character settings in your project settings.

Comment: This is the correct approach. Either use _T() or _TEXT() around your string literals, or use MessageBoxA() or MessageBoxW() which do not change whether or not the UNICODE macro is defined at compile time. Microsoft should never have introduced that stupid macro!!!